# Invalid product identifiers

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I created 2 product identifiers for my app and tested them for inapp purchase in sandbox environment. I submitted them for appstore approval process. Apple rejected the app for not providing inapp purchase details in my review notes. Since there was a bug, I rejected the binary and the 2 product identifiers, so that i can upload the new bundle. Then I added 2 new product identifiers and tried to test them in the new bundle. I got only the 2 deleted product identifiers as invalid product identifiers and did not get the newly created product identifiers in the products in this method

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

I deleted my app and reinstalled, logged out user accounts in iPhone. But nothing seems to work..! Please help me guys..!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to change the product identifiers in the request. I changed them and it started to work!